# On delete of Parent entities - null the association on the other entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to solve my issue on Doctrine ORM. I have 2 parent entities: `CompanyDoctrineEntity` and `ServiceDoctrineEntity` and 1 entity that are associated with these 2 (but the association is not required) `OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity`. The association in `OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity` is defined by:

```
class OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     *
     * @var int $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many logs have one company. This is the owning side.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyDoctrineEntity", cascade="detach")
     * @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @var CompanyDoctrineEntity $company
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * Many logs have one service. This is the owning side.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ServiceDoctrineEntity", cascade="detach")
     * @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @var ServiceDoctrineEntity $service
     */
    private $service;
}
```

[image]

My expected behaviour is, whenever either `CompanyDoctrineEntity` or `ServiceDoctrineEntity` is removed from the database, the association in the `OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity` will be `NULL`ed, which I believe what the `cascade="detach"` does, but for some reason, it's not working, as I am getting the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_app2`.`logs_order_link_redirects`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6C1CA74CED5CA9E6` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `app_services` (`id`)) in /Users/arvil/Projects/app2.test/public_html/wp-content/themes/app-theme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/arvil/Projects/app2.test/public_html/wp-content/themes/app-theme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php(117): PDOStatement->execute(NULL)
#1 /Users/arvil/Projects/app2.test/public_html/wp-content/themes/app-theme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(1054): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement->execute()
#2 /Users/arvil/Projects/app2.test/public_html/wp-content/themes/app-theme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(656): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->exe in /Users/arvil/Projects/app2.test/public_html/wp-content/themes/app-theme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php on line 49
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert on Doctrine, so take this with a grain of salt and test thoroughly.

Your relations are not `nullable` (defaults to false), which is why your foreign key constraint is complaining: `logs_order_link_redirects.service_id` (and `company_id`) isn't allowed to be null. That likely wasn't a problem before because you're not inserting the `OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity` entities without the relationships. If you were to say

```
$redirectLog = new OrderLinkRedirectLogDoctrineEntity();
$entityManager->persist($redirectLog);
$entityManager->flush();
```

you'd probably trigger the same error immediately.

Also, I don't believe you want cascade={"detach"} here. Detach would just remove the entity from this entity manager instance (in other words: for the running process), so anything you'd do to the entity after detaching it wouldn't be reflected in the database when `$entityManager->flush()` is called. On the next request, the entity would be back in the entity manager.

I believe that adding `nullable=true` to your ManyToOne's JoinColumn annotations, e.g.
`@JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)`
will get you the result you're looking for. You'll need to update your database schema afterwards for changes to be applied to the tables. Also, make sure you don't have (or add) `orphanRemoval=true` on the inverse side so Doctrine doesn't automatically remove your entities if they lose their parent.

I prefer adding the JoinColumn annotation to relationships as well, even though it's not required if you're fine with Doctrine's default field name choices. Adding `nullable=false` makes it more explicit that this relationship cannot be null. That's implied if you don't have `nullable=true`, but when I start looking at relationships and need to know whether they can be null or not, I'm usually confused by something and I don't have mental energy to spare to actively remember the default values for important attributes.